# Images not showing up in Thymeleaf image src for S3 URL

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, thymeleaf

I am passing a list of image URLs stored in S3 to my HTML page to display. However, the images are not showing up. Below is my HTML file. The p tag correctly displays the URLs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display S3 Images</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:each=" url: ${imageURL}">
    <p th:text="${url}"></p>
    <img src="${url}" width="300" height="300">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S The images show up when I hard code each URL, but obviously I don't want that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `th:src` instead of `src`:

```
<div th:each="url: ${imageURL}">
    <p th:text="${url}"></p>
    <img th:src="${url}" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the CID notation. You can read more about it:

[CID NOTATION EXAMPLE](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email-templates#emails-with-embedded-images)